# Going from one screen to another by tapping on item in list of menu items

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, android-jetpack, navigation-compose

I have an app which display list of menu items retrieved from server and stored in room database. Now i want to add another screen that should display details of item that user would click on the 1st screen.
How can i implement this? As i am using kotlin jetpack compose.

I have tried to use navigation composable & Intent but failed.

Answer (score 0):

The question is exhaustive, because it's hard to know where have you failed. I suggest you better complete this official [Compose Navigation Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation#0) for a better understanding.